# Claim of Tax Treaty Benefits of W-8BEN for New Zealand resident

Tags: united-states, income-tax, new-zealand, form-w-8-ben

I'm starting full-time remote employment with a US company soon, and they asked me to fill up the W-8BEN form. So what should I fill up on the part of Claim of Tax Treaty Benefits? I found that NZ has a Tax Treaty with US, https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-trty/newzld.pdf, but I still have no clue what I'm looking at

Comment: Why country will you be physically located in when you work?

Comment: @user102008 New Zealand, as mentioned above, although I'm Malaysia citizen

Comment: Did you find an answer for this? I am in the same situation and the best advice I could find was here - https://www.upenn.edu/pennpress/about/taxforms.html But I still don't know what the tax rate is for NZ on personal income? And what article to refer to in the tax treaty document. Here is also a useful video on how to fill it out (although again not for NZ residents) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rFZVwEUHRqg

Answer (score 0):

I believe you don't need to fill out the part on Claim of Tax Treaty Benefits. If you are not a US citizen or resident alien for US tax purposes, and you are not working in the US, your income should not be subject to US tax, and thus there would be no need to claim any tax treaty benefits for US tax purposes.